# Slow RPC calls in development mode (GWT)

Tags: gwt, rpc, development-mode

When I run my GWT application in development mode (included Jetty) in Eclipse (Helios), RPCs seem to be very slow. Firebug says that they should be ok (mostly < 1sec) but in fact I have to wait about 10-15 seconds. Browser window is freezed for that time... Everything else runs quite performant, on RPC is a problem.
Running with noserver option using a Tomcat 6, I have the same problem. But without the develpment mode (on same Tomcat) everything is fine.

Does anybody know, whats the problem with dev mode?

*Edit:*

I tried to increase memory with -Xmx1024m but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Eclipse shares resources with jetty in the development mode. Try to increase memory available for Eclipse. (I can observe similar situation on my dev box)